# How to format a Quicksight dashboard so a table visual shows all rows when exporting to pdf

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm having a problem making a table in a quicksight dashboard responsive.

The business need is to have some filters of the data, and have a couple of graph visuals but then have the raw data listed below in a table, then some more supporting analysis in a visual below the table. Then a staff member wants to print this visual to pdf to share it via email.

I have created this, however sometimes the table might have 10 lines of data and sometimes the table might have 100+ lines of data.

In the dashboard view I can only see how to resize the table based on pixels/dragging to resize.

Is there a way to say "show a maximum of 100 rows in this table" and "if the table is less than 100 rows, only show the number of rows with data" instead of having a table visual which has been created with fixed dimensions and may either show not all data, or a table with tens of empty rows.

Any help is appreciated.